# Is there a fopen-like function in elisp

Tags: file, emacs

I am aware of `insert-file-contents` idiom:

```
(defun read-lines (filePath)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-contents filePath)
    (split-string (buffer-string) "\n" t)))
```

But is there a more natural way to read a file line by line without reading the whole file at once? I am looking for `fopen`/`fread`-like functionality.

Comment: I'll just note that you can pass BEG and END parameters to `insert-file-contents` to insert only part of the file.  Not what you're asking for, but worth pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the natural way of working with files in emacs is loading the file in buffer, After that you can process it line by line. take also a look to [this answer in emacs stackexchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/19538/8892) and [this blog post](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_process_lines.html) from ergoemacs

like for example this:

```
ELISP> (find-file "foo.txt")
#<buffer foo.txt>
ELISP> (goto-char 1)
1 (#o1, #x1, ?\C-a)
ELISP> (while (not (eobp))
  (print (current-line-contents))
  (forward-line 1))
```

[image: Sample emacs interaction]

In order not to get the properties, you can use the function thing-at point:

```
ELISP> (goto-char 1)
1 (#o1, #x1, ?\C-a)
ELISP> (while (not (eobp))
         (print (thing-at-point 'line t))
         (forward-line 1))

"line 1
"

"line 2
"

"line 3
"

"line 4
"

nil
```

if you need to work with temporary bufferss for [speed reasons try](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_find-file_vs_with-temp-buffer.html) this:

```
 (with-temp-buffer
         (insert-file-contents "./foo.txt")
         (while (not (eobp))
           (print (thing-at-point 'line t))
           (forward-line 1)))
```

Comment: My problem with copying a file to a buffer is that it is horribly slow. It could be like five minutes for non-minified JSON file. Especially, it is slow when the file is a binary file or doesn't contain line endings.

Comment: I updated the question maybe it shloud work for you, now in terms of speed